# Add class css in attribute type MultiFileField?

Tags: python, django, modelform

How do I add css class in attribute type MultiFileField?

```
class FileSystemItemCommonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    path = MultiFileField(min_num=1, required=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after test in pycharm, I found this solution, FileInput in file.

```
path = MultiFileField(min_num=1, required=False, widget=FileInput(attrs={"class": "custom_file_input"}))
```